# MySQL auto increments disappeared

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a MySQL database with 60 tables. Most of the tables have primary keys (expect pivot tables). All these primary keys had the attribute `AUTO INCREMENT`.

Then over night somehow all the primary keys had that attribute removed and the default value set to 0.

I have no idea what might have caused this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improper backup/restore probably. I've recently learned that mysqldump with `--skip-opt` option will drop auto-increment index :(

Comment: If you need the other benefits of --skip-opt but also need auto increment, you can add the value --create-options; see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.mysql/Acy6jwfcZfw